# reshape pandas dataframe reversing one row into several columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe which looks like the below one. It has the ID column, the month, and whether the customer bought or not a specific product.

```
ID      Date     Buy_Or_Not
1       2016-01       1
1       2016-02       1
1       2016-03       0
1       2016-04       1
1       2016-05       0
2       2016-01       1
2       2016-02       1
2       2016-03       1
2       2016-04       1
2       2016-05       0
```

I would like to reshape it to look like this.

```
ID      2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 2016-05
1       1       1       0       1       0
2       1       1       1       1       0
```

Any advice in getting this done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 ways of reshaping

1) Using [`pd.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
In [58]: df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Date', values='Buy_Or_Not')
Out[58]:
Date  2016-01  2016-02  2016-03  2016-04  2016-05
ID
1           1        1        0        1        0
2           1        1        1        1        0
```

2) Using [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
In [59]: pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Date'], df['Buy_Or_Not'], aggfunc=sum)
Out[59]:
Date  2016-01  2016-02  2016-03  2016-04  2016-05
ID
1           1        1        0        1        0
2           1        1        1        1        0
```

3) Using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
In [60]: df.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).sum().unstack('Date')
Out[60]:
     Buy_Or_Not
Date    2016-01 2016-02 2016-03 2016-04 2016-05
ID
1             1       1       0       1       0
2             1       1       1       1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Date', values='Buy_Or_Not')
print (df)
Date  2016-01  2016-02  2016-03  2016-04  2016-05
ID                                               
1           1        1        0        1        0
2           1        1        1        1        0
```

If errors like:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).